# terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion (lldb)

Tags: c++, string

I want to convert a character to Integer and calculate its frequency but I receive this error! I am using XCODE.

terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion .

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
std::string s;
std::cin>>s;

int a[27];
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{
    int c;
    c=std::stoi(&s[i]);
    a[c]++;
}
for(int i=0;i<27;i++)
    std::cout<<a[i];

return 0;
```

}

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need `stoi` - it makes no sense here. What's the expected input?

Comment: Why are you passing an address of a string to `stoi`?  [It takes a `const` reference to a string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Input would be a string.

Comment: Of course it's a string. A string containing what characters though? Your program accepts input and produces output - show an example of expected input, and the example of the output the program is expected to produce given that input.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik if I input "aaaaaabb" the array should have the value 6 at a[1]  and 2 at a[2], considering 1-26 as alphabets in order a,b,c....z

Comment: `int c = s[i] - 'a' + 1; a[c]++;` Don't forget to initialize `a` to all zeros though - at the moment, it starts uninitialized, containing random garbage. Also, your second loop doesn't make any sense - you are looping over `a`, why are you bounding your index with the length of `s`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that helped ! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if its alpha character, then convert character to lowercase and then sub 'a' so you get value 0-25.

```
if (isalpha(s[i]))
{
    c= tolower(s[i]) - 'a';
    a[c]++;
}
```

Also you have to initialize array `a`, because it is *immediate*

```
int a[26] = { 0 };
```

And if you want to print result

```
for(unsigned int i=0;i<(sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]));i++)
{
    std::cout << a[i];
}
```

**[Here is the example.](https://ideone.com/ByiOOB)**